# Как в unix написать команду которая либо создаёт папку, либо...

Tags: unix, linux

Подскажите плиз скрипт в линукс, который бы делал следующее:

1. Проверять, существует ли папка
2. Если да, то ничего не делать.
3. Если нет, то создать эту папку

Comment: @evm Пожалуйста, не забывайте принимать те ответы на вопросы, которые вы считаете наиболее правильными и полезными.

Comment: И чего так этот вопрос подняли? Это же совсем нуби-вопрос, на который очень просто найти ответ :)

Comment: @cy6ergn0m +1, ваще не понятно…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В bash-скрипте (mkdir.sh) можно сделать так:

```
DIR=$1

if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    # Создать папку, только если ее не было
    mkdir $DIR
fi
```

Запускать как

```
$ ./mkdir.sh
```

Еще можно проверить, не является ли имя символической ссылкой:

```
DIR=$1

if [[ ! -d "$DIR" && ! -L "$DIR" ]] ; then
    # Создать папку, только если ее не было и не было символической ссылки
    mkdir $DIR
fi
```

Comment: Этот вариант имеет существенный недостаток: между проверкой и попыткой создания имеется разница во времени. Это означает, что если кто-то проскочит между, то этот вариант сведётся к ответу kirelagin'а (т.е. переменная окруженрия $? всё равно будет выставлена в один, так что этот обходной воркэраунд даёт иллюзию защиты от единицы в $?). А раз разницы нет, а вариант kirelagin'а короче и проще, то он лучше.

Answer (score 7):

```
mkdir -p
```

Создаст подкаталоги, если надо (mkdir -p a/b/c), ну и попутно не среагирует на уже созданный каталог.

Answer (score 6):

`mkdir <name> 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Этот вариант тоже хорош. Только нужно помнить при написании скрипта, что после ошибки mkdir выставит $? в единицу.

Comment: Ну никаких конкретных условий не звучало — я написал самый простой из пришедших в голову вариант :).

Comment: Да, создаёт. Спасибо. Но в скрипте, который запускается как ./some.sh на этом месте зависает(

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы забыли убрать треугольные скобочки вокруг name (имени папки) *FACEPALM*

Comment: Правильно использовать так: mkdir "$1" 2> /dev/null

Comment: mkdir "$TMP_FOLDER" 2> /dev/null 
тут зависает(

Comment: Я попробовал в точности Вашу строчку. У меня не зависает :(.